# Cómo migrar una web a un hosting diferente gerando un ssl previamente

Tags: ssl, certificado-ssl, letsencrypt

Tengo experiencia migrando webs de todo tipo (wordpress, joomla, etc).
Normalmente copio los archivos, bajo la base de datos. Subo los archivos al nuevo hosting, importo la base de datos.
Antes de hacer la migración modifico mi archivo hosts, para saber que todo está bien. Apunto a la nueva ip solo en mi pc, si veo que todo está bien, recién cambio los DNS. Aquí no había problema porque cuando comenzaba a refrescar ya se veia que apuntaba a la nueva ip y todo bien.

Ahora que estoy empezando a usar el https (SSL), tengo un problema, la mayoría de hostings a los que migro, generan el SSL después de que yo haya apuntado la IP al nuevo servidor. No es posible que genere un SSL a una ip que todavía no se apunta, esto me genera un malestar porque recibo un mensaje "el certificado ssl no es válido" y tengo que esperar a que el nuevo hosting detecte la nueva IP para que recién genere el SSL, aquí viene mi pregunta:

¿Cómo migro una web sin afectar el SSL?
¿Cómo migro una web generando el SSL antes de apuntar a la nueva ip del nuevo servidor?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres usar el programa CLI de Let's Encrypt para que genere automáticamente los certificados y modifique tu webserver (nginx o apache), no vas a poder hacerlo en una máquina cuya IP no es la oficial para el dominio. Ej

- máquina actual: 146.155.56.16 - asociada a `jhoedram.com`
- nueva: 146.155.56.12 - no asociada a un dominio

Desde la máquina nueva intentas usar [certbot](/questions/tagged/certbot) para generar el certificado de `jhoedram.com`. certbot le pega al dominio, el dominio resuelve a otra IP, certbot opina que puede ser un intento malicioso y no eres dueño del dominio. Termina el proceso.

Lo que yo haría en tu caso sería generar manualmente un certificado usando  [SSL For Free](https://www.sslforfree.com), copiarlo a la nueva máquina, configurar el webserver con ese certificado. Probar el certificado cambiando tu archivo `hosts` y luego reapuntar el DNS.

Hecho esto, de ahí en adelante puedes usar certbot normalmente en la máquina nueva.

PD: las IP de ejemplo eran las IP de los workstation en mi universidad cuando empecé a usar internet, hace 25 años. ToT

Comment: Interesante!! Nunca se me ha dado ese caso, pero lo probaré. No está de más conocer estas maniobras. Gracias!!